# Create view of a table substituting rows on condition with another table's rows

Tags: sql, substitution, multiple-conditions

I apologize for the contort title. Basically I have a table of customers' accounts, something like

TABLE 1
[image]
and I need to create a view of this TABLE 1 where, if ACCOUNT TYPE is 'shared', I substitute the corresponding row with the row of a second table, TABLE 2, where I have the details of the subjects who hold the shared accounts (e.g. I have three codes all linked with foreign key to Account 3). Of these subjects, I need to take, as substituting row, the one which has a flag on a column of TABLE 2 (e.g. column CARD).

I hope to find some clarity here because I'm fairly new to SQL and I got lost on conditions :facepalm:

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: please avoid screenshots ,also provide sample data for table2 and desired output

Comment: since no enough info provided. i would suggest to
1. left join tables, 
2. use CASE when /then to define which column you substituting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to give you some direction so you can get going, you can always JOIN 2 subsets. So you could make a selection of all ¨non-shared¨ types with a joined selection (between Table1 and Table2) of all the "shared" types.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  ACCOUNT,
  [ACCOUNT TYPE],
  SERVICE --, ...
FROM TABLE1 
  WHERE [ACCOUNT TYPE] <> 'shared'
UNION 
SELECT 
  ACCOUNT, -- or whatever data from T1 or T2 on the ¨substitute" row
  [ACCOUNT TYPE], -- or whatever data from T1 or T2 on the ¨substitute" row
  SERVICE --, ...
FROM TABLE1 T1
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON (T1.CARD = T2.CARD) -- OR WHATEVER FK JOINS THEM BOTH
  WHERE T1.[ACCOUNT TYPE] = 'shared'
    --AND T2...  -- WHATEVER OTHER CONDITIONS MAY APPLY 
; --SQL Server/SQL Azure sintax
```